# テキストの比較方法について

Tags: powershell, shell

お世話になります。とある配列やテキストをすべて比較するスクリプトを作成したいと思っております。

例　）

```
a.txt
-----
a
b
c
d

1.txt
-----
1
2
3
4
```

これをa-1,a-2,a-3,a-4,b,1,-b,2-b,3,b-4　
みたいな形でたすき掛けみたいなイメージで比較していきたいのですが、
うまく案が思いつきませんでした。

どなたかサンプルをご教示いただけないでしょうか。

当方、powershellとshellしか知りませんので、すみませんがその範囲で教えてください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 総当たりでの比較であれば、二重でループを回せば実現できそうな気がします。

Comment: エクセルなら、A列目に "",a,b,c,d/1行目に "",1,2,3,4/B列2行目に=IF($A2=B$1,"同じもの","違うもの")/以下同文

Comment: "比較"について具体的に記載できますか？ただ文字列を結合することを"比較"と言っていたのであれば質問文を修正してください。

Comment: 特に shell やらのスクリプト言語の場合、何のコマンドラインツールが使えるかによって実行可能なスクリプトの内容がかわってきます。 OS は何を想定していますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

比較ってこんな感じのことなのかなぁ…。

```
cat a.txt | while read LINE_A
do
  cat 1.txt | while read LINE_1
  do
    printf “${LINE_A}  と ${LINE_1} を”
    printf “比較したら ”
    if [ “${LINE_A}” = “${LINE_1}” ] 
    then
      printf “同じもの”
    else
      printf “違うもの”
    fi
    echo “でした”
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
join -j 65535 -t "-" a.txt 1.txt | sed -e "s/^-//" > merge.txt
```

emasakaさんの回答に補足。
区切り文字の指定と行頭の区切り文字を削除しファイルへ出力

Answer (score 0):

Linuxの場合、joinコマンドで存在しない列を指定すると、テキストの行の組み合わせが得られます。

```
$ join -j 100 a.txt 1.txt
 a 1
 a 2
 a 3
 a 4
 b 1
 b 2
 b 3
 b 4
 c 1
 c 2
 c 3
 c 4
 d 1
 d 2
 d 3
 d 4
```

「比較する」が具体的に何をするのかわからないので、とりあえずここまで。